# Get mongodb document by key

Tags: mongodb

I have collection "my_data" with this data structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("533afcb07f8b9af4118b4567"),
  "usd" : {
    "eur" : {
      "total" : "50000000000",
      "course" : "1.3"
    },
    "gbp" : {
      "total" : "60000000000",
      "course" : "1.4"
    }
  },
  "eur" : {
    "usd" : {
      "total" : "70000000000",
      "course" : "1.5"
    },
    "gbp" : {
      "total" : "80000000000",
      "course" : "1.6"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get array (usd.eur)

```
{
  "total" : "50000000000",
  "course" : "1.3"
}
```

What is the best way to do it via mongodb?

Comment: As far as I can see usd.eur is not an array. Nevertheless, the mongodb 'find' has a projection parameter that you can use to get only some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following command in Mongo Shell. And check the answer.

```
db.my_data.aggregate({$project : {'usd.eur' : 1, _id : 0}}).result[0].usd.eur
```

Comment: sorry, it was example. I have updated my first message, please take a look.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I am new to Stackoverflow. I'll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: Wed Apr  2 09:10:17.612 TypeError: Cannot read property 'usd' of undefined

Comment: IF `db.my_data.find()` returns the JSON which you have provided then the command which I have provided should work.
Can you check what happens with `db.my_data.find()` command?

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake. all works great, thank you my friend!